# Is-a and Has-a Problem mapping foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

In my program I realize a problem when it get a inheritance and a oneToMany relationship. That is:

I put to run. It will create the tables, without the foreign key. But when I remove the Inheritance annotations, and run again. It creates as foreign.

Class Employer

```
package com.example.TablePerConcreteClassExample.model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Employer")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="Employer")
public class Employer {

@Id 
@Column (name = "empNo", nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int empNo;

@Column(name = "name", nullable=false)
private String name;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "employer",
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

public int getEmpNo() {
    return empNo;
}

public void setEmpNo(int empNo) {
    this.empNo = empNo;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
    return vehicles;
}

public void setVehicles(List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
    this.vehicles = vehicles;
}


}
```

And Class Vehicle

```
package com.example.TablePerConcreteClassExample.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Vehicle")
public class Vehicle {

@Id 
@Column (name = "id", nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable=false)
private String name;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "empNo", nullable=false)
private Employer employer;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public Employer getEmployer() {
    return employer;
}


public void setEmployer(Employer employer) {
    this.employer = employer;
}


}
```

And my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TablePerConcreteClass?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.database.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

I expected a inheritance and in the vehicle table a Employer's foreign key.

The actual results are the inheritance, but no foreign key. But when I remove inheritance annotations, the foreing key will be created.

Comment: It is permitted to use inheritance together with entity relationships, and I have not spotted an error in your code.  Possibly, then, you've stumbled upon a flaw.

Comment: Do you already do something like that?